# TSQL Features in SQL 2008 Vs SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What are the advanced Features With SQL2008 over SQL2005 Particularly with TSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big one for me, although it's not really T-SQL related, is intellisense. About time too :)

As for the language...

T-SQL finally got shortcut assignment in 2008:

```
SET @var *= 1.18
```

The `MERGE` statement allows all sorts of modification goodness, based on the results of joining tables together.

There are a bunch of GROUP BY enhancements, like GROUPING SETS, and operations on cubes.

There are new datatypes to play with

- hierarchyid, useful in self-referencing datasets
- date and time can be treated separately
- geography and geometry, for GIS systems and other geographical applications

There are a few others too. See [the official new features page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645577.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 1):

There are new features like-

- Compound Assignment Operators i.e. +=, -= etc.
- Increased size support for user defined data types.
- Four new date and time data types.

It is all covered here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270.aspx

cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is Standard way to insert many rows with single INSERT statement:

INSERT INTO Tab VALUES
(...,...,...),
(...,...,...),
...
(...,...,...)